# Save google form data into mysql database using ngrok

Tags: laravel, api, google-forms, ngrok

I am trying to save google form data into the database using ngrok tunnel but i am getting a 404 not found error in ngrok terminal. I don't know what I am doing wrong any help or suggestions will be really appreciated.

[image: This is the error that I am getting ngrok terminal]

[image: This is my webhooks configuration]

```
Route::post('/employee-leaves', [LeaveFormSyncController::class,'store']);
```

This is my post route in VS code.

[image: This are my route list]

Comment: Is the endpoint working without ngrox? For example with Postman. Can you show the output of `php artisan route:list`, so we can see what middleware you are using.

Comment: @Thijs I have added the route list above.